# How can I hide everything after the nth delimiter in an HTML element?

Tags: html

I have an HTML element that contains a list of synonyms. I only want the first 5 synonyms to be displayed.

In the example shown below, can I use CSS to hide everything after and including the 5th comma for each element with the "synonyms" class?

Example:

```
<div class="synonyms"> talkative, garrulous, voluble, over-talkative, long-winded, wordy, verbose </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done with CSS, but you can use JavaScript to replace the `textContent` of those elements.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.synonyms').forEach(d => {
  d.textContent = d.textContent.split(", ").slice(0, 5).join(", ");
});
```

```html
<div class="synonyms"> talkative, garrulous, voluble, over-talkative, long-winded, wordy, verbose </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not familiar with JavaScript, but I tried to put this code at the top of the html file and it isn't working for me. Could you please let me know what I'm doing wrong? Here's what I have: `<script>

document.querySelectorAll('.synonyms').forEach(d => {
  d.textContent = d.textContent.split(", ").slice(0, 5).join(", ");
});


</script>


<div class="synonyms">a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h</div>`

Comment: @user17038038 You need to put it just before the closing `</body>` tag or put the code inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{/*...*/})`.